# Google + is closing in April 2019 is this the same as google chrome?

Tags: windows-7, window

Will Google Chrome be closing in April of 2019? I am not sure if Google Chrome is the same as Google x.

Answer (score 4):

## No. They are different

Google+ is a social media platform owned by Google. When they say that Google+ is closing, they mean that all the posts/images/everything else on Google+ will be deleted, and you won't be able to use it anymore.

Google Chrome is a web browser also made by Google. However, that is not shutting down and it is not linked to Google+.